Should Resampling be used in an AB test?
I have a sample of 14,000 users, 7,000 in the control and 7,000 in the treatment. The metric in question is numerical. Both groups are skewed right with a Bernoulli distribution.
While one possible solution would be to use a t-test alternative, because of non-normality, this is a downstream decision, so procedural-wise the decision to perform resampling should occur before the decision of which test to use. I will completely ignore the type of test to use.
Rather, this question concerns the preliminary rule-of-thumb of whether to perform resampling. Should resampling be applied to this AB test?

that question was about which test to use. This question is about resampling, as noted in the title.

A bit unclear why this was marked as duplicate, could you elaborate? This question is about resampling, whereas the other question was about which test to use. TIA!
